# Hibernate Exception - could not locate named parameter [:laboratoryId]

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, parameters, hql

I have the following query in Hibernate.I got Hibernate Exception and I don't understand why Hibernate throws this exception. Could anyone help me?

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();

session.createQuery("delete from Laboratory l where l.id=:laboratoryId")
        .setParameter("laboratoryId", laboratoryId).executeUpdate();
session.close();
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace that you got...

Comment: could not locate named parameter [:laboratoryId]

Comment: is there any specific requirement for using named parameter. Why can't ? instead of named parameter 
session.createQuery("delete from Laboratory where id = ?")
    .setParameter(0, laboratoryId)
    .executeUpdate();

Comment: @andy, update your question with complete stacktrace of the issue.

Comment: @Chaitanya, 'could not locate named parameter [:laboratoryId]' is complete stackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some spaces between the `=` sign and the bind name `:laboratoryId` and remove the alias:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();

session.createQuery("delete from Laboratory where id = :laboratoryId")
    .setParameter("laboratoryId", laboratoryId)
    .executeUpdate();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that laboratoryID has value? For my query builder I used something like this:

```
if (!laboratoryId.isEmpty()) { 
        query.setParameter("laboratoryId", laboratoryId());
        }
```

also same thing for query

```
  "delete o from Laboratory o"

if(!laboratoryId.isEmpty()){
query.append("where o.id = (:laboratoryId)")

}
```

But I used it for String values

Please show code for laboratoryId - is it user input or what?

Comment: I tried what @Avinash Perla suggested (("delete from Laboratory where id = ?") .setParameter(0, laboratoryId) .executeUpdate();) and it works. I don't understand why it works just like that, but I'm happy that it works.

Comment: hibernate is  a smart guy :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

DELETE Clause

The DELETE clause can be used to delete one or more objects. Following is the simple syntax of using DELETE clause:

```
String hql = "DELETE FROM Employee "  + 
         "WHERE id = :employee_id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("employee_id", 10);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);
```